# How to encode 24 frames into one 24bit RGB image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to add Blender support for a light field display device.
The way the display works with standard HDMI cable is the video has each 24bit RGB frame store 24 monochrome frames. The display splits those frames as it receives them.
Here’s an illustration:

[image]

For this to work, of course, the monochrome frames must be properly encoded in a single 24bit RGB image first. Can PIL, Pillow or another Python library allow to do this?

Comment: Do you mean each monochrome frame is only 1-bit deep? Can you write some Python that synthesizes 24 frames of a rectangle or something simple, or provide a zip-file with 24 frames in it and also show how the result should look? Thank you. It may be as simple as shifting and ORing the frames together - or is some maths required?

Comment: Yes, each monochrome frame is 1 bit. "It may be as simple as shifting and ORing the frames together - or is some maths required?" - I don't know, that's part of the question.

Comment: If you can share the frames as a zip-file or somehow, I can try and see.

Comment: I can provide 24 binary frames, but not the combined RGB frame since I don't know how to generate a proper combined image. Will that do?

Comment: Here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EgpZXStaGXW3eC-OPvmnjMpG67y4YF0i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not production quality, but probably enough to get you started, I think it must be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

w, h = 192, 192

# Create RGB output array h, w, 3
out = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)

file = 1
# Iterate over 3 channels, Red, Green and Blue- or maybe B, G, R
for channel in range(3):
    # Iterate over the 8 bits in each channel
    for bitpos in range(8): 
        filename = f"{file}.png"
        print(f"Opening {filename} as bit {bitpos} of channel {channel}")
        im = Image.open(filename).convert('L') 

        # Convert to Numpy image with range 0..1
        ni = (np.array(im)/255).astype(np.uint8)

        # Shift and stuff into output array
        out[...,2-channel] |= ni << (bitpos) 
        file += 1

result = Image.fromarray(out)
result.save('result.png')
```

**Sample Output**

```
Opening 1.png as bit 0 of channel 0
Opening 2.png as bit 1 of channel 0
Opening 3.png as bit 2 of channel 0
Opening 4.png as bit 3 of channel 0
Opening 5.png as bit 4 of channel 0
Opening 6.png as bit 5 of channel 0
Opening 7.png as bit 6 of channel 0
Opening 8.png as bit 7 of channel 0
Opening 9.png as bit 0 of channel 1
Opening 10.png as bit 1 of channel 1
Opening 11.png as bit 2 of channel 1
Opening 12.png as bit 3 of channel 1
Opening 13.png as bit 4 of channel 1
Opening 14.png as bit 5 of channel 1
Opening 15.png as bit 6 of channel 1
Opening 16.png as bit 7 of channel 1
Opening 17.png as bit 0 of channel 2
Opening 18.png as bit 1 of channel 2
Opening 19.png as bit 2 of channel 2
Opening 20.png as bit 3 of channel 2
Opening 21.png as bit 4 of channel 2
Opening 22.png as bit 5 of channel 2
Opening 23.png as bit 6 of channel 2
Opening 24.png as bit 7 of channel 2
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like you've nailed it. I'll test the code soon. What does the line "out[...,2-channel] |= ni << (bitpos)" do?

Comment: That's exactly the crucial line :-) `ni` is a Numpy array containing the PNG file, scaled to be 0 or 1 - it's 0 or 255 in the input file. Then `<< bitpos` shifts that bit left to the correct position, one bit further left for each subsequent file. The `|=` means that the result is ORed into the output array on the left. The term `out[..., 2-channel]` is the same as `out[:,:,2-channel]` and it means the current image is put into `channel-2` of the output array. It is reordering because your files appear to be in BGR order, else it would be simply `channel` if they were RGB ordered.

Comment: That's odd, I've exported the image from GIMP as indexed, 2 color only PNG.

Comment: They show up in **ImageMagick** and **PIL** as 2 colour where those two colours are 0 (black) and 255 (white).

Comment: I'm confused, you said my files have pixels in BGR color order, yet there are only two colors? Do you mean two colors visually, but still stored as (0,0,0) and (255,255,255)? Even then I don't think the reading order should matter, right (BGR vs RGB)?

Comment: The input files I started with have one of two values for each pixel, either 0 or 255. I change them to be 0 or 1 where I divide by 255. The RGB/BGR thing is whether  files `1.png ... 8.png` represent Blue or Red in the output image. I am sure files `9.png..16.png` represent Green in the output image. And files `17.png..24.png` probably represent Red. Make a test image which is just Red with no Green or Blue and see how it comes out. If it is Red, the code is correct. If it is Blue, you need to change `2-channel` to just `channel`.

Comment: I see, yes the device expects the binary frames stored in RGB order.

Comment: Cool, well we can make it either using `channel` or `2-channel`. The real question is what order the PNG files are in, i.e. if `1-8.png` are Red or Blue.